# react js using hooks and redux-saga rerender a component repeatedly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I'm trying to fetch data using redux-saga. in result it renders my component over and over again every 2 or 3 seconds.
this is my component :

```
const Farms = props => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.listFarms();
    }, []);

    console.log(" [ FARMS ] let see that works :", props.farms);

    return (
        <div> </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        farms: state.farms
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps ={ listFarms }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Farms);
```

and this is my saga generator:

```
function* getAllFarms () {
    try {
        console.log(' [ farms saga ] all farms');
        const allFarms = yield call(getFarmsAsync);

        yield put(listFarms(allFarms.data))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(' [ farms saga ] ERROR');
    }
}
```

this is my console output : ( it doesn't stop )

[image]

anybody knows where is my mistake?

Comment: I think you have an infinite loop because `useEffect` is called every time the component is rerendered and every time the useEffect is called you download new data which causes new rerender and so on and so on. You need to modify the `useEffect` to call `listFarms` only on first render.

Comment: @Marting Kaldec your are not right because useEffect has empty dependencies array and will run on mount only after the component render for the first time.  @Tannaz Shirzadi try using redux hook  `useSelector` and `useDispatch`

Answer (score 0):

From your code and the console output, it is clear that you are invoking `getAllFarms` worker saga again and again using `yield put(listFarms(allFarms.data))`.

In other words, `getAllFarms` worker saga is listening to the action produced by `listFarms`, therefore it is being executed recursively.

Comment: do you mean listFarms in in mapDispatchToProps ? what should I change?

Comment: to suggest what you need to change, you have to provide more code ... can you share your sagas , and saga configs, etc.... can you put your code in sandbox and share the link ... or any github link to refer?

Comment: unfortunately I work for a company and it is illegal to share the codes

Comment: np - i understand... you can share a few lines of code where you configure saga watchers... basically , your main problem is that the line  `yield put(listFarms(allFarms.data))` is calling the `getAllFarms`  function... you have configured it somewhere in such a way  .....